419 Error in Laravel 11 during registration
I am encountering the following error in my new installation of Laravel 11 and Vue.js when I try to submit a form, in this case, the Register form.

419 | PAGE EXPIRED

I have checked this question and yes, I do have @csrf in my register form and
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Steps to reproduce

I installed a fresh instance of Laravel 11:

composer create-project laravel/laravel test
cd test/


I added the laravel/ui package

composer require laravel/ui


I added the Vue.js and Auth UI

php artisan ui vue --auth

It gave me a warning:

The [Controller.php] file already exists. Do you want to replace it? (yes/no) [yes]

I typed yes then [Enter].

I installed the npm packages and initialized vite

npm install && npm run dev


Iniatilized the dev server and tried to register

php artisan serve

Edit
There are additional steps that were done on the same repo. We work with mongodb hence we added the MongoDB configurations as well.

Installed the laravel/mongodb package

composer require mongodb/laravel-mongodb


Added the configurations in config/database.php as below:

'mongodb' => [
    'driver' => 'mongodb',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'assets'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'options' => [
        'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'),
    ],
],


Updated .env file as shown below:

DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=testdb
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

I am hoping there's someone with a solution.
NB I tried to install Laravel 10 and do the same processes and it works perfectly. What has changed in Laravel 11? Any help is appreciated.
Edit
Below is the contents of my bootstrap/app.php.
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

and register.blade.php
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
  @csrf
    <div class="row mb-3">
    // Rest of code


This is strange, I've tried it on a fresh Laravel 11 installation and didn't get the same problem. I tried the exact same steps in your question as well.
Can you please update your question with the contents of your bootstrap/app.php file?

I've added the contents in the question. Also, how did you get the fresh install? Using this command: composer create-project laravel/laravel test

Yes, I've just copy-pasted the commands from your questions and they all worked fine. Anyway, the boostrap/app.php file looks good to me.
Okay, let's try something else: check your .env file and look at the SESSION_LIFETIME variable. Is it set to 0?

Nope, its 120: SESSION_LIFETIME=120

@EyadBereh I have added some information I did not have before. When using sqlite (Laravel 11's default) its working, but when I added the mongodb installation, the error occurs.

I've added the register.blade.php snippet where I initialize the register form. This is the default register page, I have not made any modifications to it.

The issue here obviously has something to do with MongoDB (which I have zero knowledge of). Try switching the SESSION_DRIVER variable to file instead of the default database one.

If the database is the default, just make sure you've created the table for it. php artisan session:table --connection=mongodb The error also points to this. It can't save the sessions, so each request gets a new session, but this means even if it received the CSRF token that matches the previous session, it no longer matches the new one.

@EyadBereh This is the answer. When I made the switch of SESSION_DRIVER=file it worked perfectly. You should set it as the answer so that I upvote it, for anyone else stuck on this.

Hi, I am having this problem with laravel 10. I really would like to understand why it is happening. Why can't I use database as a session driver? have you figured that out?

The idea was that if you want to use SESSION_DRIVER: database, then first run php artisan migrate

It seems like you're using the database driver as your session driver. This is the default since Laravel 11.
I'm sure that this problem has something to do with MongoDB, but I would suggest you to use the file session driver, you can do this by setting the SESSION_DRIVER variable inside your .env file to file:
SESSION_DRIVER=file

Eitherway, in your case I don't see why you would need to use a database to store your sessions. Using filesystem is much faster and has way smaller overhead.

Starting from Laravel 11, database usage has become default. Session Configuration At first, I didn't understand where the problem was... I still had the older parameters in mind. By the way, could you provide some information on why you recommend using files specifically? Just in a comment here, in case there's a good article or summary about it, I'd be interested to learn more.

@rozsazoltan I suggested using the filesystem as a driver to store sessions because read/write operations to files are faster than those that happen to the database, and also let's not forget that with each incoming request the server is fetching the session's data, so wouldn't it be better to be fetched from the filesystem rather than the database.

@rozsazoltan There's also one more thing here I would like to mention: you're interacting with the sessions through the session() helper to retrieve the data you want, and you don't care whether it's stored inside a nice database table or a messy raw file, it doesn't matter to you, you're just getting your data and that's all that matters.

@rozsazoltan database as a session storage can be helpful in such scenarios where a session may be shared across multiple front-ends, but you can still setup a redis cluster for that purpose, it's blazing fast and allows better scalability.

Thank you for sharing your opinion and perspective! It's very helpful to examine functionality from different viewpoints. Now I fully agree with your comment that for a very basic small project, using the files may be sufficient and even better. However, if load balancing or better scalability is needed, transitioning smoothly to a database is advisable, or setting up Redis or Memcache for much better performance.

@rozsazoltan You're welcome! I'm glad to see that there good people here on Stack Overflow who are willing to discuss and talk, and not just downvote

Although the question doesn't explicitly mention it, I believe you've switched the default database to MongoDB as well.
Since this was set up this way after installation, it may be necessary to regenerate the table for the Session.
In Laravel 11, this command would have been automatically executed by php artisan migrate, but it was performed before installing MongoDB. I assume that after migrating to the new database, you would need to rerun the migrate command separately. Otherwise, only the session table can be created manually.
php artisan make:session-table

More information

Session:_Driver Prerequisites (database) - Laravel Docs


This is also an acceptable answer. I had not run the php artisan migrate command.
